# How to play APE (Monkey's audio) files?

Tags: sound, file-format, codecs

How can I play APE (Monkey's audio) files in Ubuntu 11.10?

Thanks in advance!

---

**Solution:**
I finally installed `ffmpeg` as duffydack suggested, using the instructions from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Then i converted the ape file to flac format:

```
ffmpeg -i inputaudio.ape outputaudio.flac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audacious and Banshee play APE files fine.  I have the ubuntu-restricted-extras package installed if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and I'm using Audacious, but still no luck. I get "No decoder found for file ..."

Comment: really?  strange.  Try enabling the medibuntu repository and update the restricted packages  run this in terminal,  `sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && 
sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update` and do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: a last alternative is to just convert them with ffmpeg.  compile it from source, its quite simple with this guide.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095  , then you would use it in terminal something like `ffmpeg -i file.ape -ab 256k -f mp3 output.mp3`